# Install MAMP (not PRO) For PHP And Mail Sending

Tags: macos, gmail, switching, email, php

I first tried searching here at apple.stack but couldn't find a solution that seemed to work for me, so I'm trying my hand at posting a question. I already spent a few good hours trying to make it work, since I **overall** would like to keep using MAMP (again, not MAMP PRO) instead of switching to another package that might give me more road blocks..

History:

- I'm a total newbie to Apple's OS.
- I have recently moved to using a macbook pro with Lion OS installed for my PHP development.
- I had come to a point in my development where I now have to send mail.
- I created a gmail account since the project I am working on hasn't got a name yet so no domains have been purchased (meaning no other smtp server to use)
- I installed MAMP (**not PRO**) and have been programming on the macbook pro up to this point
- I have installed pear using: http://blog.stealth35.com/2011/07/27/install-pear-on-osx-lion.html
- Then after following the advice: `You may want to add: /usr/lib/php/pear to your php.ini include_path` I have modified:

  `include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php"`

  to

  `include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/pear"`

  in this file: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
- I restarted the MAMP server and performed the test:

  `<?php`
  `require_once 'System.php';`
  `var_dump(class_exists('System', false));`
  `?>`

  And got a `bool(true)` response.
- When trying out the example here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php code at post: `roberto dot silva at mexicoshipping dot net 24-Jan-2004 12:16`
- And still.. nothing.. roberto's post ended up giving me the following:

  `Warning: include(Mail.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/signupemailtest.php on line 24`

  `Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mail.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/signupemailtest.php on line 24`

  Line 24: `include("Mail.php");`

  Which makes sense, because I can't seem to find the file `Mail.php` anywhere.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution for it? I'm moving towards testing confirmation emails and signups, and this has killed my streak.. If I'm missing any other info please let me know. I haven't provided other code since I'm already stumped at the inclusion of `Mail.php` and so far, I have been able to follow: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78799 properly.. but so that it doesn't go off-topic, I'd just posting info about getting the mail extension/pear mail set up. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but is Swift Mailer an option for you? Sidesteps the PEAR dependency and works very, very nicely. If not, you'll probably get a better response on SO.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the pear library, not with OSX. You should consider reposting this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since this hasn't gained an accepted answer and has been here for more than a month - it would be fine to seek a migration to another site if the OP prefers it. It's clearly on topic here and several other sites (Super User, Stack Overflow, perhaps Server Fault based on the expertise of the setting where the server stack it being run) so it's not something we would shove on another site unless the OP seeks that transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you solved this, but you need to make sure the PEAR Mail extension is installed. Open your Terminal and enter: pear install Mail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help,  but I was looking at the example code and noted that you have an uppercase "M" in Mail.app. Should it be lower case?

Comment: Thanks, David.. I the `Mail.php` file was in its correct case; the expected output file when installing pear should have the letter m in capital case..